# Home button reopens the app instead of showing the launcher

Tags: samsung

I am using a Samsung Galaxy A41 (Android 10, One UI 2.5) , and I am experiencing a strange behaviour: sometimes when I press the home button, instead of going to the launcher, the current app reopens itself.

As far as I remember, the problem started after installing [Niagara Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bitpit.launcher) and Sesame; I was actually convinced that the problem was in the launcher itself, but after uninstalling both the launcher (moving back to Nova Launcher) and Sesame, the problem still happens.

I have not found any pattern for it: it happens with different apps, and randomly. I've tried to change the navbar (buttons vs gestures), remove accessibility permissions to apps.